# hello ... can anyone tell me how i would encode html ( wich hard to decode )

Tags: encode

i was just want any way >>> any site >>> that encode html .... i want to encode the 
copyright of designer some site ...

this is the code or the right ..

---

```
<div class="blftr">
<del class="nothing">--</del><font size="1" color="#B42D04">Designed© by </font> <a href="skype:belal.m.ibrahim">
<font class="beltex1" color="#565353">Belal</font><font class="beltex2" color="#565353">.M.</font><font class="beltex3"     color="#565353">IBrahim</font></font> </a><b><del class="nothing"><font color="#B42D04" size="0">
```

and hard to decode the html code

is there any thing ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can include javascript, replace your code with

```
<script language='Javascript'>
document.write(unescape('%3C%64%69%76%20%63%6C%61%73%73%3D%22%62%6C%66%74%72%22%3E%0A%3C%64%65%6C%20%63%6C%61%73%73%3D%22%6E%6F%74%68%69%6E%67%22%3E%2D%2D%3C%2F%64%65%6C%3E%3C%66%6F%6E%74%20%73%69%7A%65%3D%22%31%22%20%63%6F%6C%6F%72%3D%22%23%42%34%32%44%30%34%22%3E%44%65%73%69%67%6E%65%64%A9%20%62%79%20%3C%2F%66%6F%6E%74%3E%20%3C%61%20%68%72%65%66%3D%22%73%6B%79%70%65%3A%62%65%6C%61%6C%2E%6D%2E%69%62%72%61%68%69%6D%22%3E%0A%3C%66%6F%6E%74%20%63%6C%61%73%73%3D%22%62%65%6C%74%65%78%31%22%20%63%6F%6C%6F%72%3D%22%23%35%36%35%33%35%33%22%3E%42%65%6C%61%6C%3C%2F%66%6F%6E%74%3E%3C%66%6F%6E%74%20%63%6C%61%73%73%3D%22%62%65%6C%74%65%78%32%22%20%63%6F%6C%6F%72%3D%22%23%35%36%35%33%35%33%22%3E%2E%4D%2E%3C%2F%66%6F%6E%74%3E%3C%66%6F%6E%74%20%63%6C%61%73%73%3D%22%62%65%6C%74%65%78%33%22%20%20%20%20%20%63%6F%6C%6F%72%3D%22%23%35%36%35%33%35%33%22%3E%49%42%72%61%68%69%6D%3C%2F%66%6F%6E%74%3E%3C%2F%66%6F%6E%74%3E%20%3C%2F%61%3E%3C%62%3E%3C%64%65%6C%20%63%6C%61%73%73%3D%22%6E%6F%74%68%69%6E%67%22%3E%3C%66%6F%6E%74%20%63%6F%6C%6F%72%3D%22%23%42%34%32%44%30%34%22%20%73%69%7A%65%3D%22%30%22%3E'));
</Script>
```

This does not include the closing div, since you did not have it in your original post